# Convert textarea model to array

Tags: html, angularjs

I am new to angularjs. I have textarea as below.

```
<textarea class="form-control" maxlength="100" ng-model="EmailList"></textarea>
```

The user enters data in the text box as a list in the textarea (as below).

```
Data1
Data2
Data3
```

My model is also updated in the same way entered in the textarea, when checked with console.log(as below).

```
Data1
Data2
Data3
```

I want to separate the each line value into an array. But I dont have any separator available to spilt the data. Can you please help me on this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: _"each line"_ contradicts _"dont have any separator available"_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular offers [ngList](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngList) that does exactly that:

```
<textarea ng-model="list" ng-list="&#10;" ng-trim="false"></textarea>
```

Every line will end up as entry the the array `list`.